# jQuery Append events issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a for-practice card-game design, and I'm stuck with the adding to hand animation. For once, I thought that using append and then adding the even handlers would work, but it turned out it only works for the last appended element (in this case li).
here is the code on jsfiddle for easier testing..

The code:

```
$('.deck .card').on('click', function () {
    // $(this).appendTo('.hand')
    $('.hand').append(this)
    $('.hand .card').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('flip')
    })
})
```

I tried moving the click event for hand outside the deck, but it didn't work at all.
also, here is the code in jsfiddle for easier testing http://jsfiddle.net/FAZUc/9/

thanks.

Comment: Weird...if you click really fast it starts flipping in reverse order

Comment: Just remove the click event on the clicked element before you add a new one. Also, only target the clicked element. `$(this).off('click').on('click',...` http://jsfiddle.net/FAZUc/16/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the click event from the clicked element, then add the new click event to only the clicked element.

```
$('.deck .card').on('click', function () {
    // $(this).appendTo('.hand')
    $('.hand').append(this)
    $(this).off('click').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('flip')
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FAZUc/16/

Event delegation makes it even easier.

```
$('.deck').on('click', '.card', function () {
    $('.hand').append(this)
});
$('.hand').on('click','.card', function(){
    $(this).addClass('flip')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FAZUc/18/

Comment: Ive added a few cards and it looses the event completely

Comment: does the event delegation version have the same issue?

Comment: Event delegation one is doing the same :\. Add a few cards and the handlers just kind of stop working

Comment: yes, if you click on the green card really fast, it loses all events

Comment: i'm running chrome too... you know the green card only flips once, right? that's because the flip is done by adding the class, and i'm just adding the class, not toggling it.

Comment: thanks, it did work the exact way I wanted it to. :)
would using backbone make this easier?

Comment: I have no idea, i've never seriously used backbone.